# How to get asp.net core razor validators to display on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, razor-pages, onload

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2 Razor pages. When my page loads, no validation messages are shown until the page is submitted. How can I get the validation messages (ie. "Required", etc.) to display automatically when the page is loaded? I want the user to see which entries are required before he/she submits the page.

Comment: You use model state to add error messages and make the model state invalid and then pass the model to the view. This will display the error message along side the inputs. Normally model state is changed to invalid during POST action to inject the error message when some custom validation fails.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the code would look like?